# setText causes crash after second implementation?

Tags: android, textview

```
public void displayCurrentLocation(){
    mCurrentLocation=mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    TextView coordinates = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
    coordinates.setText(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+", "+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            displayCurrentLocation();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Just testing the concepts here. I am trying to get an updated current location every 2 seconds and display it in a TextView. I set this up so that it would do it once, but when I added the timer, it will setText once, but the next time it crashes. What is wrong?

Comment: please paste your logcat error ..

Comment: post code of `displayCurrentLocation();` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 I am trying to get an updated current location every 2 seconds and display it in a TextView.
```

My guess (based on above comment) is you are updating ui from a Timer task. Timer tasks runs on a different thread. You can't update ui from it. You need to update ui from a ui thread.

Use a `Handler` or `runOnUiThread`

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     // update ui here
    }
});
```

`Handler` is a better option.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

So if you create handler on the ui thread it is bound to it and you can update ui there.

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ; 
int timeleft=100;
m_handler = new Handler(); 
m_handlerTask = new Runnable() 
{ 
@Override
public void run() {
      // do something
  m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 2000); 
 }
 };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

To cancel the run

```
  m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); // cancel run
```

Answer (score 1):

`Timer` runs in a separate `Thread` and where as you can not touch the UI views in non UI Thread...

use `Handler` of a TextView or `runOnUiThread()`

this may help you...

```
 public void displayCurrentLocation() {
    mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView coordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
            coordinates.setText(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() + ", "
                    + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());             
        }
    });
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            displayCurrentLocation();
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this only updates the coordinates once, or the value is not changing.